# jMeter thread sequence

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, jmeter

I have a JMeter test plan with following http request samplers.

1. Login
2. Call some functionality which needs a logged in user
3. Logout

When I execute the test plan with 5 parallel threads, I see that the sampler 2 is called before calling sampler 1 for some threads, which then fails the response assertions.

Is there any way to specify a sequence of samplers to be executed ?

Comment: What makes you think that Sampler 2 is executed ahead of Sampler 1? Requests are executed sequentially, top down, and this is very unlikely to fail so perhaps there's an issue with how you're interpreting the results.

Comment: Because I see in the view result tree that  when I start with 5 parallel threads the login is called 4 times then the other page which fails the assertion that there should be a logout button.

Comment: "View result tree" doesn't reflect the per-thread sequence, it's not a reliable source (because some thread may execute faster than the others).

Comment: But the issue for me remains that the assertion fails exactly  for the tests where view result tree doesn't show the correct sequence.

Comment: Hi, It is true that the threads are called in sequence. So I examined a bit in detail and found that there are redirects from the server, sometimes which resets the cookie to empty string. I don't know why the servers sends empty cookies spradically, but this is what is happening. How can I deal with this ?

Comment: @ant, check my comment earlier. I figured out that it is not the problem with the sequence. I get the reset cookie header from the server in some of the http requests. May be it is a problem with the application, but it works from the browser without any problem.

Comment: @rangalo You should read the third paragraph from my answer. You probably have a problem with context.

Comment: @Oliver Lloyd I already have HTTP Cookie Manager. Most of the requests work fine, but sporadically server sends all the blank cookies. May be it is something with the app, although the app works from the browser.  As it is a black box test, I don't know much about the app except that it is built with Tapestry.

Comment: @rangalo You may have a Cookie Manager but, nonetheless, based upon the problem as you describe it, you still probably have a problem with context.

Comment: @Oliver Lloyd I think you are right, but I don't know any other way except the cookie manager to fix the issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should ensure that they are executed sequentially :

[image]

So let's start with thread group.

Number of Threads(users) is 5.

So assuming you have the logic work out for your login sampler. Just add additional sampler to it. So right click on that sample `Add > Post Processors > BSF PostProcessor`, inside this post processor big script space write `${__setProperty(ThreadValue,${__threadNum},)}`.

This will save the thread number to your property called `ThreadValue`. Make sure you select your language as `beanshell` in the dropdown list.

Then after the login sampler add the if controller. Add this to the condition field `(${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok}==true) && (${__property(ThreadValue,,)} == ${__threadNum})`

What this means is that -> do only logged in stuff while the actual login is successful and if the login thread matches the thread you're currently in.

That's it you do your login stuff only inside the if controller. If you want to be sure that you logout the right user place additional if controller arround it.

Cheers

Comment: can I validate if login is success based on response code here ?

Answer (score 2):

What you need to consider is that each thread is a separate entity, like a real user, and that it has it's own session, but that JMeter is designed to execute these threads asynchronously, ie. in parallel. The View Results Tree listener displays all activity, from all threads *as it happens* regardless of the logical thread sequence. If you would rather have 1 thread make 5 iterations then simply change the thread count to 1 and use a loop of 5 and this will preserve the sequence (although this defeats the point of using a load testing tool like JMeter!).

If you do change the thread count to 1 then you can see the true, logical sequence of execution in the results tree. This will show each sampler being executed, in sequence, top down.

Now, in your case, I suspect you have a problem not because things are being run out of sequence but rather because the server is losing the session context between requests. This is very common and more often than not you can address the problem using a [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cache_Manager) or with the use of a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor).